# Invoke SOAP based service using Apache Camel and spring-ws component

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-ws, spring-camel

I have SOAP based service which accepts some predefined request object,

for example, AccountRequest having some fields.

Sample code

```
from("direct:test")
    .routeId("account.get")
    .process(exchange -> {
        exchange.getIn().setBody(createAccountRequest());
    })
    .to("spring-ws:http://localhost:8090/AccountServices/AccountOverviewService")
    .log("Got Request for account-detail");
}
```

Above code throws an error

```
org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException: 
No type converter available to convert from type: 
com.test.AccountRequest to the required type: 
javax.xml.transform.Source with value com.test.AccountRequest@4e1c1763
```

Is this right way to invoke soap service via camel?

Dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>2.18.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-spring-ws</artifactId>
    <version>2.18.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Why are you using `spring-ws` ? I am not familiar with that component. I usually use `cxf:...`

Comment: Even i am not familiar with anyone so trying it, can you send a sample to do the same using cxf:?

Answer (score 2):

Here's how my SOAP WS example looks using `cxf`.

Firstly, in `camel-context.xml`, define the web service bean:

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="insuranceService"
                 address="http://localhost:8080/insuranceService"
                 serviceClass="com.mycompany.insurance.insurancePort"
                 wsdlURL="schema/InsuranceService.wsdl">
</cxf:cxfEndpoint>
```

Now the camel route looks like this:

```
from("somewhere")
    .to("cxf:bean:insuranceService")
```

And you might need some dependencies like these:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-cxf</artifactId>
        <version>${framework.camel}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
        <version>${framework.cxf}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-http</artifactId>
        <version>${framework.camel}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-jaxb</artifactId>
        <version>${framework.camel}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-soap</artifactId>
        <version>${framework.camel}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-saxon</artifactId>
        <version>${framework.camel}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: How to send custom body i.e custom object in request body.

Comment: Like you did in your code, set the in body via the processor, or maybe this can help: `.setBody(constant("abc"))`

Answer (score 1):

You would need to marshal the "com.test.AccountRequest" to the xml by adding

```
  JaxbDataFormat jaxb = new JaxbDataFormat(false); //add
  jaxb.setContextPath("com.accountservice.model"); //add - path to your generated stubs

    from("direct:test")
        .routeId("account.get")
        .process(exchange -> {
            exchange.getIn().setBody(createAccountRequest());
        })
        .marshal(jaxb) //add
        .to("spring-ws:http://localhost:8090/AccountServices/AccountOverviewService")
        .log("Got Request for account-detail");
    }
```